# Passing string parameters in JQuery function

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on the following piece of code:

```
function moveLeft() {
        if ($('#show-slider ul').is(":animated")) return;
        $('#show-slider ul').width(slideWidth*(slideCount+1))
        $('#show-slider ul li:last-child').clone().prependTo('#show-slider ul');

        $('#show-slider ul').css('left', - slideWidth).animate({'left': 0}, 333, function() {
            $('#show-slider ul').width(slideWidth*slideCount).css('left','');
            $('#show-slider ul li:last-child').remove();
        });
    };

$('.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });
```

Here I want to pass **#show-slider** as a string in **moveLeft()** function.

I know how to pass variable parameter as given below:

```
var abc = '5';

function meraFunc(abc)
{
    alert(abc + " Some Text" );
}

$('#test').click(function() {
    meraFunc(abc);
});
```

Here's the fiddle in short - http://jsfiddle.net/codestor/hxzd9/

And this is something which I want to achieve:

```
function moveLeft() {
    // alert "#show-slider" in this line
    // alert "#show-slider ul" in this line
    // alert "#show-slider ul li" in this line
};

$('.control_prev').click(function () {
     moveLeft("#show-slider");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hxzd9/2/)

Use this,

The class name is `control-prev` and not `control_prev`

```
$('.control-prev').click(function () {
     moveLeft("#show-slider");
});

function moveLeft(id) {
    alert(id);
    alert(id + ' ul');
    alert(id +' ul li');  
};
```

Comment: the alert says undefined

Comment: Check the updated code. Do you have element `#show-slider` . SHow your Full HTML

Comment: Oh you've written the code to display the contents of #show-slider class. That's not what I wish to do. I just want to pass #show-slider as TEXT and display that very specific passed text as an alert. If I understand how to do that, I can use it to replace all #show-slider TEXT inside moveLeft function. This will allow me to use moveLeft as a single function for different function calls. So I can later call moveLeft("#abcd") and all the content inside moveLeft function will become #abcd ul, #abcd ul li and so on